# Show multiple images in action sheet

Tags: swift, image, segue, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Only one image shows on the action sheet at the moment, how can I get it to show two images?[image: image of action sheet]

```
@IBAction func areaAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    haptic.prepare()
    haptic.impactOccurred()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let areaImage = UIImage(named: "Areas")
    let area = UIAlertAction(title: "Area", style: .default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newArea", sender: self)})
    area.setValue(areaImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), forKey: "image")
    alert.addAction(area)

    let project = UIAlertAction(title: "Project", style: .default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newProject", sender: self)})
    let projectImage = UIImage(named: "Projects")
    area.setValue(projectImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), forKey: "image")
    alert.addAction(project)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The difference between the two is the `handler` of the action. Just replace `nil` in the second snippet with the closure in the first one.

Comment: Yes that worked but it only shows one of my images next to an option and not both.. updated above to show

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check if the image is not `nil`

Comment: for project I get `<UIAlertAction: 0x282ecc6c0 Title = "Project" Descriptive = "(null)" Image = 0x0>` at a breakpoint

Comment: The image is `nil` (does not exist, name is misspelled)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func areaAdd(_ sender: Any) { 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil,      preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let area = UIAlertAction(title: "Area", style: .default, handler: { action in 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newArea", sender: self)
    })
    let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
    area.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
    alert.addAction(area)
}
```